# Flask FileStorage file becomes empty after creating ZipFile object

Tags: python, flask, python-zipfile

I'm trying to save a .zip file received from an endpoint, but first check the contents of the .zip.

If I do:

```py
import zipfile
from Flask import request

file = request.files["file"]
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(file, "r")
// some operation to check zf
file.save("path/to/save/file")
```

The saved file is empty. However, removing the construction of the ZipFile object, the file saved is not empty. Any advice on why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to post the solution I found.

Adding

```
file.stream.seek(0)
```

to move the file pointer back to the beginning, before

```
file.save("path/to/save/file")
```

solves it.